# Custom or dynamic @JsonProperty for all fields without annotation with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm looking for a way to customize the serialized keys and deserialized setter calls for jackson.  I have a few hundred objects that are all somehow related with various levels of abstractions and interfaces, however they don't have many inherited fields. I am using a mixin that applies to all my classes to utilize a filter and a TypeIdResolver.  All of the fields I want serialized to json end in 'attribute', but I don't want attribute after every key in the json. I'm unable to refactor the field and method names as it's used for legacy XML parsing and I can't break that. I really don't want to add @JsonProperty to every field;  I'm looking for something more dynamic.  Some way to inspect fields to serialize or keys to deserialize and modify it to my liking.

For deserialization, I think I might be able to use InjectibleValues, but I haven't tried as I haven't been able to find anything to customize the output keys.

for example,

```
String nameAttribute = "xyz";
getNameAttribute()

"name"="xyz"
```

Not

```
"nameAttribute"="xyz"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with a custom extension of JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.  I overrode the methods that look for @JsonProperty and provided my own logic.  I also had to implement my own hasIgnoreMarker() to avoid placing @JsonIgnore all over the place because the filtering doesn't happen until the actual serialization so I was getting errors about duplicate getters and setters.

```
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new MyAnnotationIntrospector());



private static class MyAnnotationIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    
    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
        if (a instanceof AnnotatedField) {
            String name = a.getName();
            if (name.endsWith("Attribute")) {
                return PropertyName.construct(name.replace("Attribute", ""));
            }
        }
        return super.findNameForSerialization(a);
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForDeserialization(Annotated a) {
        if (a instanceof AnnotatedField) {
            String name = a.getName();
            if (name.endsWith("Attribute")) {
                return PropertyName.construct(name.replace("Attribute", ""));
            }
        }
        return super.findNameForDeserialization(a);
    }
```